# Why is my stackoverflow reputation missing 2200+?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, reputation

Why is my [stackoverflow reputation score](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2589776/herohuyongtao) suddenly missing 2200+? What's going on here??? I have about 2250+ reputation earlier today, but now only 16 left. Also my user name has been changed...

Hope it's not my new year gift... :(

Comment: Do you have the privileges you normally would, indicating it's just a display issue?

Comment: @Servy Almost all the privileges are also missing...

Comment: Your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2589776/user2311113?tab=reputation) seems to add up to more than 16. I think you're getting hit with the same bug as reported earlier.

Comment: Just wondering... did you go on a handbag-promoting streak or something? That's the only way I can think of for this to happen legitimately.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Really weird. Hope this bug can be fixed soon.

Comment: @Undo What's `handbag-promoting streak`? I have no idea about it.

Comment: Hopefully the devs are back from their holiday and recovered from any celebrating they did, so it will get addressed soon. The good news is that it appears to be some kind of caching issue that goes away on its own after some time.

Comment: @herohuyongtao Spamming stuff - at one point there was a huge influx of handbag spam. A valid spam flag automagically deducts 100 rep from your score.

Comment: @Undo Where can I see about spamming stuff about me if any?

Comment: @Undo let's not scare him that much.... given the suer name changed, this seems like the bug. :-)

Comment: @herohuyongtao you'll have to change your user name back yourself, but most users who have experienced it seem to have the rep return automatically sooner or later, so site tight and it will eventually return

Comment: @psubsee2003 I hope so. Thanks.